# How to preserve the Colors in my image sequence?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

I rendered 2 separate image sequences and I'm trying to combine them equally. Like one on top of the other without loosing the quality or color of either. I want my fireball image sequence as the top most layer, but I don't want it to pick up any of the background so it keeps the vibrancy and shape. I can tell in the image input node that the fire is faded because of the alpha, but idk how to tell blender to ignore the alpha in the fire.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you use alpha over instead of z combine? also why haven't you excluded the foreground from your background render?

Comment: @L0Lock The Alpha Over helped preserve the shape which is great thank you!! It's still factoring in the alpha of the flame though. 

I animated the fire ball and the fog with shaders. however It was very taxing on my computer to render both animations at the same time. So I render the fore ground and back ground separately.